# what does nn.Linear in pytorch represents?

Tags: python, pytorch

Does nn.Linear in pytorch represents only one unit? and if so the weights of one unit that accepts only one input and passes one output is just one? and if i pass a vector as an input to the unit then it will do scalar multiplication?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`nn.Linear` represents one layer that contains multiple units.

**How many units?**
This depends on the `out_features`. If you pass `out_features=1` there will be one unit, if you pass `out_features=10`, there will be 10 units and so on.

**Does it use scalar multiplication?**
No, it doesn't. It uses matrix multiplication, to get benefit of `vectorization`.